# Admission Test - Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm going to have a uni admission test and so I found some past year problems and I found this one that I really cannot resolve.

$f(x) : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is an integrable function such that

$f(x) \leq \int_0^x \! \sqrt{f(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t.$ Find f(x)

The solution is $f(x) \leq x^2 \ \ \forall x \in [0,1]$

Differentiating on both sides:

$$y' \leq \sqrt{y}$$
$$y' \cdot y^{-1/2} \leq 1$$
Now we integrate
$$\frac{y^{1/2}}{1/2} \leq x+c$$
$$\sqrt y \leq \frac{1}{2} (x+c)$$
and with $f(0)=0 \rightarrow c=0$
$$y \leq \frac{1}{4}x^2$$

It isn't the right solution, could you help me please?
I think I made a mistake when I've differentiated the right side but I can't understand why

Comment: Do you think you can derivate $f$?

Comment: If I take $f(x)=x^2$ then $\sqrt {f(x)}=x$ so your integral is $\int_0^x x\,dx=\frac {x^2}2=\frac 12f(x)$ so your original inequality fails.  Hint:  The ODE $\frac {dy}{dx}=\sqrt y$ is separable.

Comment: @Wyllich why not?

Comment: @lulu in fact that is the case of equality

Comment: I don't understand your point.  The function $f(x)=x^2$ does not satisfy the original inequality (nor the limiting equality)  for the reason I gave (unless I botched the calculation).

Comment: @Matte I may be wrong but there is no hypothesis which explicitly says the function is differentiable.

Comment: Worth saying:  your notation is very misleading.  $\left( f^2(x) \right)'$ would mean "the derivative of the function $f^2(x)$" but that's not what you want.  You want "the square of the derivative of $f(x)$" (though in fact it is better to just leave the square root where it is).

Comment: Trick: for display-style math, use `$$` at both ends instead of `$` ;) and welcome to Math SE!

Comment: @lulu I edited my question, I found a solution but it isn't right

Comment: That function certainly satisfies the limiting case of equality.  Why do you think it is wrong?  (Note:  I haven't thought about the inequality aspect of the problem, just the limiting equality).

Comment: because the text gives f(x)<=x^2 as the solution, maybe the text is wrong?

Comment: As I say, $x^2$ does not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Oh no @lulu sorry, I was really convinced that it worked but, checking it for almost the hundredth time, I've understood, thank you very much :)